# How to map out param which is Array of SQL UDT in JAVA?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a procedure which returns Array of SQL user-defined type. I had mapped only the SQL User defined object to java object by implementing SQLData.

How to map complete Array of custom user defined objects?

Output from oracle stored function is something like this:
`ORG.RESULT([ORG.answer],[ORG.answer],[ORG.answer])`

I am using `CallableStatement` in JAVA to call the stored function. I was wondering if it is possible to get the value of the column by column name like it is there in ResultSet.

Comment: please share the code snippet, you have, to understand the issue in hand

Answer (score 0):

The [ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) can give you access to the information of the COlumn returned.

Here is a small example from the Javadoc to know if the first column (`a`)  could be used in a where clause (this is a specific example ^^ )

```
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
 boolean b = rsmd.isSearchable(1);
```

You will see that the metadata have a methods to get informations like column names, types, count, ... you can use those to get every information you want without know the order of the values or the names.

You can easily mixed a `getColumnCount` with a `getColumnName(int index)` to get the names and then get the values from the ResultSet itself.

Comment: Thanks AxeIH. This can be used when we call a query right? I was wondering if we have anything equivalent like the one u mentioned when we call stored procedure/function. To the best of my understanding, we can fetch the value by index param not by column name. I am looking for something like this -->                               resultSet.getLong("DB_Column_Name);

Comment: @user2975747 A `Callable Statement` can return a ResultSet too (it extends `PreparedStatement` after all). I've never tested the metadata on a Callable result but I doubt this could do a difference. I don't have a DB to test this right now, but if I found some times tonight (it's 7AM here), I will try.